# How to remove duplicate rows from a data frame based on a count variable

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am trying to remove duplicate rows using a count variable (basic) and/or a coder variable (preferred). The goal is to take a database and then remove duplicates based on a count variable "recode" which is > 1 some of the time.

UPDATE: For clarification, the desired output is the df with just one entry per "id" variable below.

Here's my attempt at a MRE. I wrote a for-loop to try to remove ALL BUT one of the rows that have the same id variable based on "recode" > 1. This seems suboptimal based on some other threads I've looked at (though I've not seen a solution I understand). This MRE seems to actually work, but the method doesn't work with my real data.frame. I think it's because it just implements the 'last' deletion on the intact df, rather than all the deletions for each id.

```
    x <- structure(list(A = c("5.1", "5.1", "6.2", "7.3", "5.1", "6.2", "6.2", "5.1"), 
    B = c(4, 4, 3, 1, 4, 3, 3, 4),
    C = c("A","B","C","A","B","C","D"  ,"E")),
    .Names = c("id", "count", "coder"),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA, -8L))
    
    
    for (i in c(1:length(x$id))) {
      count <- x$count[i]
      if (count > 1) {
      indices <- which(x$id == x$id[i])
      indices_sub <- indices[-1]
      # print(indices)
      # print(indices_sub)
      x2 = x[-indices_sub,]
      }
    }
```

For context, my data is from a survey that is filled out by five RAs ("coder"). The five RAs code the same show sometimes. So many shows have 2-5 entries. I need to eliminate duplicates. A first solution is just keep the first one (which is what I'm starting...and struggling...to do here). But that's arbitrary and bad. A slightly-better solution step would be to retain the entry based on a coder hierarchy, let's call: A, B, C, then D. If A, then keep A; if not, then if B, keep B; if not, then if C, keep C; if not, then keep D.

Comment: Hello, can you make the expected output more clear? What about any of `dplyr::distinct(x, count, coder, .keep_all = TRUE)

dplyr::distinct(x, count, .keep_all = TRUE)

dplyr::distinct(x, coder, .keep_all = TRUE)`?

Comment: @dcsuka These work, thanks. I was able to adapt this to select based on coder A then B then C ```x <- x %>% 
  arrange(id, coder) %>% 
  dplyr::distinct(id, .keep_all = TRUE)```

Answer (score 0):

The expected output is still a bit fuzzy to me, but I think you're looking for something akin to a SQL windows function to identify a "first" record by some coalescing ordering criteria.

```r
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(id, count, coder) %>%
  mutate(row_num = row_number()) %>%
  filter(row_num == 1) %>%
  # to remove helper column
  select(-row_num)
```